# how to format the Bluetooth portable printer?

Tags: java, android, printing, android-bluetooth

I'm using a portable printer to print a receipt out. I don't quite understand about it...

**Here Is the format.**

[image]

How can I format the 'Header 1' font size bigger than others And also set all headers to the middle?

**Here is the code**

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mSQLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Information", null);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                txn = new SettingModel();
                String header1 = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("header1")));
                String header2 = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("header2")));
                String header3 = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("header3")));
                String header4 = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("header4")));
                String txnNo = "TxnNo: " + D_Txn.getText().toString();
                String name = "Name: " + D_Name.getText().toString();
                String amount = "Amount: " + D_Amount.getText().toString();
                String Date = "Date: " + Select_Date.getText().toString();
                String Users = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("personInCharge")));
                String space = "";

                header1 += "\n";
                header2 += "\n";
                header3 += "\n";
                header4 += "\n";
                txnNo += "\n";
                name += "\n";
                amount += "\n";
                Date += "\n";
                Users += "\n";
                space += "\n";

                outputStream.write(header1.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(header2.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(header3.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(header4.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(txnNo.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(name.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(amount.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Date.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(Users.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(space.getBytes());
                outputStream.write(space.getBytes());

                Toast.makeText(this, "Printing Text...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Is there anyway to put a space? I'm using a empty string, is it correct?

Comment: I actually miss the concept of "formatting a printer"...

Comment: It's hard to find the formatting of a printer...

Comment: I still have to understand what the "formatting of a printer" means, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ....set all headers to the middle?

To set text to center, use this

```
  byte[] center = new byte[]{0x1B, 'a', 0x01};
```

then use `outputStream`

```
  outputStream.write(center);
  outputStream.write(header1.getBytes());
              ...
```